# Verify If Entity Was Modified In Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there an easy way to verify if an entity was updated instead of keeping tracket of a flag when testing if some properties have changed on a code first entity framework entity?

```
bool hasChanges = false;

if (existingEvent.Gender != tournament.Gender)
{
   hasChanges = true;
   existingEvent.Gender = tournament.Gender;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can do it like this.

```
DatabaseFactory.Get().Entry(existingEvent).State
```